# Escape field inside Control loop

Tags: silverstripe

New to SilverStripe and trying to decypher how things work.

I have a field in a page which I used to store some HTML code. When you view their "Holder" page, it loops over each child page and displays them all. The problem I am running into is that when I output the value it's escaping it - so I need to be able to decode it.

```
<% control Children %>
    <h2>$Title </h2>
    $ExtraHtmlBody <!-- This is escaping when outputting -->
 <% end_control %>
```

So I tried to add a function inside my Page_Controller, but it seems that I can not call Page_Controller methods from inside the Control loop. I tried moving the function into the Page class, but it doesn't seem to have any data for $this->ExtraHtmlBody. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: What datatype is your "ExtraHtmlBody" in $db? As it contains HTML it probable should be HTMLText or HTMLVarchar. As of Silverstripe 3.1 default casting is Text. http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/3.1/changelogs/3.1.0

Comment: It was just Text. I just tried changing it in my class, and edited the page again and still escaped. Is there anything I need to do to update the changes I make in Page class?

Comment: ehm well, /dev/build - and edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You data might already be escaped in the database itself. did you check?

Like @munomono said, if you are storing html use `HTMLText` or `HTMLVarchar`.
You can also try to disable auto-escaping in your template with `$ExtraHtmlBody.RAW` (at your own risks).

some info here:

- http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/data-types#casting-html-text
- http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/security#what-if-i-can-t-trust-my-editors
- http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/templates#formatting-and-casting

Your controller function problem is probably just a scope  issue since `<% loop %>` changes the scope, `$Up`/`$Top` might help. But you probably don't need that function anyway.

Comment: Ahh, .RAW fixed it. Had no idea about that feature.

Comment: well, it isn't advised and most likely a security issue (but narrowed down the issue). Hence using `HTMLText` or `HTMLVarchar`. @LouisW did you try changing the field type? Remember to run `/dev/build` after...

Comment: no offense @colimba but just want to make sure not to build wrong reference marked as solution. apropos reference (hopefully not to confuse even more) one can also set static $casting = array('ExtraHtmlBody' => 'HTMLText'); but it's not needed in this case, since it's default for HTMLText datatype.

Comment: hence the links to the documentation and security pages.